# CKEDITOR 3.6 : How to remove 'Anchor' plugin from toolbar config based on some condition.?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

> I am using CKEDITOR 3.6.

I want to remove an 'Anchor' plugin from the toolbar configuration based on some condition. I am adding the toolbar values as below.

```
var isAnchor="False";
config.toolbar = 'MyconfigTool';

 switch (toolbarType) {
    case "formatLink":
        config.toolbar_MyconfigTool= [
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
            ]
            break;
    case "findLink":
        config.toolbar_MyconfigTool= [
            ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
            ]
            break;
            }
```

And now i want to remove that added 'Anchor' plugin from that toolbar if `isAnchor='false'`.
How can i do this.

I have tried the following but i can't success

```
 if(isAnchor== 'False'){

    config.removePlugins = 'Anchor';

}
```

And i dont want to rebuild that toolbar again. I just want to remove that added plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just "rebuild" toolbar. You would have to hack the source pretty badly to achieve that. Normally, entire editor has to be reinitialized with the new toolbar config.

Comment: I understand that. While using the `config.extraPlugins` its adding an new plugin then why its not removing the added plugin.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. Your code is incorrect, because that plugin is named `'link'`, not `'Anchor'`. So if you want to remove it, just use `config.removePlugins = 'link'`. However, I still don't know if this is what you want, because link plugin adds two buttons - link and anchor. And of course this configuration will affect editor only if set before editor initialization.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar. I dont want to remove whole 'link' plugin. i just want to remove anchor only. Is that possible..?

Comment: You have to remove `'Anchor'` from toolbar config (in your case it's  `toolbar_MyconfigTool` array). That's all.